# Spring AOP for authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

Below is a sample code for my question.

Aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AuthAspect {
    @Around("execution(*com.myClassA.save()) || execution(*com.myClassB.save())") {
         Method method = call.getTarget().getClass().getDeclaredMethod(name, new Class[]{String.class, authLoader.getEntityClass(), String.class});
         // check auth for method
    }
}
```

AuthLoader class

```
@Component
public abstract class AuthLoader {
    // some methods
}
```

MyClassAAuthLoader class

```
@Component
public class MyClassAAuthLoader extends AuthLoader {
    // implementations
}
```

MyClassBAuthLoader class

```
@Component
public class MyClassAAuthLoader extends AuthLoader {
    // implementations
}
```

How can I set relevant extended class in Aspect?

I am new to AOP in Spring.

Thanks

EDIT:
MyClassAAuthLoader provides access to type A actions. Other provides access to type B actions. A user can send requests for either A or B type actions. AuthAspect should decide which AuthLoader child class to be used.

Comment: Are you using `spring-security`?

Comment: No. I am not using Spring security.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I am not sure what you mean by "set a class" in your aspect.